# Permission denied while using child_procees.exec firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to execute a binary file of [cpdf](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries) in my firebase function using the nodejs native child_procees.exec() In local tests works fine, but when I deploy my function I get this error in the logs:

```
Error: Command failed: /user_code/cpdf -pages file.pdf
/bin/sh: 1: /user_code/cpdf: Permission denied
```

There is a way to give that permissions?
Here is my code:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec
var executablePath = path.join(__dirname,'/cpdf')//<-my binary file compiled for linux 32 bits
var filePathIn = path.join(os.tmpdir(),'/file.pdf')
exec(`${executablePath} ${filePathIn} -pages`, 
function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null){
         console.log('error',error)
    }else{
         console.log('ok',stdout)
    }
})
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are the unix permissions on the file in your filesystem just before you deploy it?

Comment: Actually I'm using Windows in local development, with a windows binary of cpdf and the folder doesn't have any particular permissions

Comment: Yeah, so it's probably being uploaded without unix execute permissions.  You're going to have to figure out a way to get the file uploaded or changed after deployment with unix execute permissions.

Comment: Can you give me some advice to achieve that? I think it's not possible to modify the uploaded files. I've tried even change the file permissions with linux but obviously it didn't work. I've been working on this all day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. The fact is that the `node_modules` folder has execution permissions, so I've added in my package.json an npm repo for [node-cpdf](https://github.com/ONode/node-cpdf/) that contain the necessary binaries and then using it's routes to the executable. Here is my code updated:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec
var executablePath = path.join(__dirname,'node_modules/cpdf-n/bin/cpdf-linux-64')
var filePathIn = path.join(os.tmpdir(),'/file.pdf')
exec(`${executablePath} -pages ${filePathIn}`, 
function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null){
         console.log('error',error)
    }else{
         console.log('ok',stdout)
    }
})
```

Comment: I just changed my project directory from `\desktop` to another drive `d:\`. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need read- and executable permissions

```
sudo chmod 755 /user_code/cpdf
```

or

```
sudo chmod -RX /user_code/cpdf
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but tell me something.. Where I have to execute it? in my local folder or in the function?. I've tried to execute the next code serverside
exec('bash -c /user_code/cpdf -pages file.pdf') -> "Permission denied"
exec('chmod 777 /user_code/cpdf') -> "Permission denied"
exec('sudo chmod 777 /user_code/cpdf') -> "sudo not found"